# Java equality of floats and doubles

Tags: java, floating-point, double

I was working through debugging a program of mine where certain doubles and floats were not equal to each other. I have looked for answers previous to posting this on here as to why this would happen but could not find much relevant information. For example:

```
System.out.println(4.4f == 4.4);
```

This prints false while,

```
System.out.println(4.5f == 4.5);
```

Prints true.

Could someone shed some light on why this is the case in JAVA?

Comment: This is not the case with Java.  This is the case with floating point numbers.

Comment: That question is asked twice every week, in a form or another. Hint: there are an infinity of decimal values, but only 2^32 float values, and 2^64 double values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you write `4.4f`, that results in the closest value representable as a `float` to the true value 4.4.

When you write `4.4`, that results in the closest value representable as a `double` to the value 4.4.

When you write `4.4f == 4.4`, that tests if the closest value representable as a `float` is still the closest value representable as a `double` to 4.4, which is false; `double` has more precision, and neither `float` nor `double` can represent 4.4 exactly.

Both `float` and `double` *can* represent 4.5 exactly, however; since they're using binary fractions, and 4.5 is an exact binary fraction, that works fine.